# How to add numbered section folding to rmarkdown

Tags: r, markdown

I am trying to show sections of text only after clicking on them (very much like code folding).

So far I am using the following html script at the beginning of my Rmd file:

```
  <script language="javascript"> 
    function toggle(num) {
      var ele = document.getElementById("toggleText" + num);
      var text = document.getElementById("displayText" + num);
      if(ele.style.display == "block") {
        ele.style.display = "none";
        text.innerHTML = "show";
      }
      else {
        ele.style.display = "block";
        text.innerHTML = "hide";
      }
   } 
  </script>
```

But whenever I use it for sections/headers I lose the automatic numbering.

```
<a id="displayText" href="javascript:toggle(5);"><h1>I would like to code fold this section 
</h1></a>  
<div id="toggleText5" style="display: none">  
Bla bla 
</div>
```

And get a heading with numbering like this:

1 - I would like to code fold this section